# Modifying a GNU LGPL v 2.1 code and license

Tags: licensing, lgpl, gnu

I have found a piece of code online (https://github.com/kenkendk/sharpaescrypt/blob/master/Source/SharpAESCrypt.cs) licensed under GNU LGPL v 2.1

If I would like to make some changes to this file and re-distribute it under the same license (GNU LGPL v 2.1) do I update the copyright date or owner name (in order to reflect the changes), or retain the original one?

Comment: For a github thing, you might make a pull request. Don't change the owner name but add your own name as contributor. YMMV. And don't change the license (e.g. to GPLv3+) without permission from the original author. But I am not a lawyer!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, your comment really deserves to be made into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented,  for a [github](https://github.com/) thing, you might make a [pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/). Don't change the owner name but add your own name as contributor (and update the copyright years). YMMV. And don't change the license (e.g. to GPLv3+) without permission from the original author (unless you are *sure* that your license is upward compatible with his one, and even then you'll better discuss that with him). But *I am not a lawyer!*

The original author has then the ability to incorporate your changes, and the github platform offers an easy way to do that for him (or her) if he / she wants to, if your changes are organized as a pull request.

In general, you'll rather try to cooperate & interact with the original [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) project authors and community. [Forking a project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28software_development%29) is often frowned upon.